# Installing Ubuntu with Windows 8 Dual boot

Tags: system-installation

I have created a partition for Ubuntu, are there any extra steps I need to take before I install it?

I decided to do a dual boot of Ubuntu with Windows 8. Are there any foreseeable problems with doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.. you have done basic things to install Ubuntu.

but if you wish to run heavy application in Ubuntu such as video editing or such kind of heavy works, then it is good to create another partition for SWAP space. simple idea of swap space is that it behaves like a virtual memory when the RAM is full.you could shrink a partition of size as same as RAM or recommended is 1.5 times of RAM. I recommend you to create this swap space if you have plenty of free space in hard Disk.

and when installing Ubuntu, don't choose "install alongside with Ubuntu" option in setup.sometimes it makes problems. So choose "Something Else" option out there and proceed.

Good Luck

Comment: So, essentially, I would be installing a version of Ubuntu that would be capable of using 1.5 RAM, for example a machine that hats 4 gb RAM in in it? So, I would have three partitions, one for windows, one for Ubuntu, and one for the SWAP?

Comment: yes ..there would be 3 partitions as you mentioned. and remember that swap partition which is sized 1.5xRAM is used when the physical Ram memory is not enough for handle ongoing tasks. otherwise Ubuntu will use physical RAM memory as it is. you can observe this in System monitor in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

As minion91 said:

-Choose "something else"

-Make a swap-partition (primary partition, ext4-journaling format,size it about 1,5x your RAM)

-Make a root-partition (the "/" symbol, primary, about 15 GiB)

-Make a home-partition (logical, ext4-journaling, use the free space remaining)

Install and enjoy your dualboot-PC.

Cheers.